# Check value existence in two lists and gather the result in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I have two lists of protein sequences, I have to check every entry's existence in the two lists, say like

```
list A = [1,2,3,4]
list B= [3,4,5]

result = [
[1, true, false],
[2, true, false],
[3, true, true],
[4, true, true],
[5, false, true]
]
```

I did it this way. Not sure if it's the *right* way

```
def FindDifferences():    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v6_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[0], delimiter='\t')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v9_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[2], delimiter='\t')
    v6_set = set(df1['name'])
    v9_set = set(df2['name'])
    result = []
    for val in v6_set:
        if val in v9_set:
            result.append([val, True, True])
        else:
            result.append([val, True, False])
    for val in v9_set:
        if val not in v6_set:
            result.append([val, False, True])
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['name', 'inv6', 'inv9'])
    result_df.to_csv('result_csv.csv', index=False, header=False)
    return
```

Comment: I can't test this code or any improvements without the `txt` files.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry about that I don't have the permission to release those files :(

Comment: I don't expect to see the real thing.  But to get good answers you need to post something that works (and is small)  The smart thing is to identify the core of the problem and post it, along with some 'toy' data.  Instead of including the file read/write just give some toy values of `v6_set` etc.

Comment: @hpaulj the real data is almost exactly the same after filtering out the useful columns. literally, two lists containing strings instead of the toy ints

Comment: Just in case anyone is curious. The real pythonic way to do this is in the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847053/pandas-dataframe-check-intersection-and-fill-in-a-new-dataframe/42847164#42847164

Comment: Does the order of the results matter?

Comment: That SO answer is the kind of minimal example that I was looking for.  And to be picky, it's `panda-ionic`, not `pythonic`.  It makes good use of `pandas` methods, not general Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### General problem

It's not much, but for your general problem, mathematically speaking, I'd split the logic into three steps (*It might be a bit more code, but personally speaking, it keeps things cleaner*):

---

1. I'd intersect `list_A` with `list_B`:

   ```
   def intersect(list_A, list_B):
       return [[x, True, True] for x in set(list_A).intersection(list_B)]
   ```

   Which is going to give you:

   > `[[3, True, True], [4, True, True]]`
2. Then, I'd do `list_A - list_B`:

   ```
   def a_diff_b(list_A, list_B):
       return [[x, True, False] for x in set(list_A).difference(list_B)]
   ```

   Which is going to give you:

   > `[[1, True, False], [2, True, False]]`
3. Then, I'd do `list_B - list_A`:

   ```
   def b_diff_a(list_A, list_B):
       return [[x, False, True] for x in set(list_B).difference(list_A)]
   ```

   Which is going to give you:

   > `[[5, False, True]]`

---

#### [Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))

> In mathematics, the intersection A ∩ B of two sets A and B is the set
>   that contains all elements of A that also belong to B (or
>   equivalently, all elements of B that also belong to A), but no other
>   elements.

#### [Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))

> In set theory, the complement of a set A refers to elements not in A.
>   The relative complement of A with respect to a set B, also termed the
>   difference of sets A and B, written B ∖ A, is the set of elements in B
>   but not in A. When all sets under consideration are considered to be
>   subsets of a given set U, the absolute complement of A is the set of
>   elements in U but not in A.